# EFS CSI Mount timeout

Tags: kubernetes, csi

I have a CSI drive which is installed in my Kubernetes cluster. Also, I have created a storage class for EFS in ReadWriteMany mode.

When I launch multiple pods it fails to mount efs to the node intermittent. the only log message is in the pod is EFS mount Timeout.

There are no other error logs in CSI drive ds or a control manager

Answer (score 0):

After debuging for hours found that there was issue with Runc in the node .

AMI details:

kernal: 5.4.117-58.216.amzn2.x86_64

dockerd: 19.03.13-ce

containerd: 1.4.1

**runc: 1.0.0-rc93 [ Buggy RunC]**